# Trigger en mysql para validar campos de 2 tablas distintas, sintaxis error!

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

e simplificado mi consulta para facilitar un poco las cosas, lo que quiero lograr es que al momento de yo insertar un registro de persona en la tabla "persona1" mediante un disparador busque en la tabla "persona" si existe este registro y mande a la tabla "ok" si coincide el nuevo registro o no y plasme un disparador que compara el nuevo id_persona1 con el de la tabla persona.id_persona pero al momento de guardar un registro en la tabla "persona1" dice que la tabla "persona" no existe...
Anexo imagen y consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Con cuántas tablas estás trabajando? sería bueno que mostraras la estructura con la que estás trabajando. Y qué trata de hacer tu trigger?

Comment: actualice mi post, donde ya no me muestra un error de sintaxis, pero ahora cada que quiero agregar un nuevo registro a mi tabla persona1 me aparece que la tabla donde voy a comparar esta otra no existe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En MySQL no puedes comparar un dato con el de una tabla con un simple `new.id_persona=persona.id_persona`, debes ceñirte al SQL y usar un `SELECT`. Más o menos así:

```
DECLARE n INT;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO n FROM persona
  WHERE id_persona=NEW.id_persona1;
```

Después ya puedes aplicar el condicional y realizar la inserción. Te paso la definición completa del disparador para que puedas comprobarlo:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS valida_persona;
CREATE TRIGGER valida_persona
  BEFORE INSERT ON persona1
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE n INT;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO n FROM persona
      WHERE id_persona=NEW.id_persona1;
    IF n>0 THEN
      INSERT INTO ok (info,instante,id_persona) VALUES
        ('Coincide id',NOW(),NEW.id_persona1);
    END IF;
  END;
```

Aporto también las tablas en SQL con las que he montado el ejemplo mínimo para hacer las pruebas:

```
CREATE TABLE persona(
  id_persona int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  );
CREATE TABLE persona1(
  id_persona1 int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  );
CREATE TABLE ok(
  id_ok int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  info varchar(31),
  instante datetime,
  id_persona int,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_persona) REFERENCES persona(id_persona)
  );

INSERT INTO persona VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO persona1 VALUES (11);
SELECT * FROM persona;
SELECT * FROM persona1;
SELECT * FROM ok;
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias David, ahora queda probarlo con diferentes tablas
Saludos!