# TRIGGER_BEFORE_INSERT Y SIGNAL SQLSTATE

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas **"productos"** y **"ordenes"** se supone que con el trigger se debe validar el campo cantidad de la tabla productos y si la cantidad que se quiere ordenar es mayor a la cantidad existente, deberá *arrojar un mensaje de error* usando el SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' pero también si la cantidad que se quiere ordenar es menor o igual a la cantidad existente, *deberá actualizar la tabla productos con la nueva existencia.* Ya lo desarrollé y mi lógica dice que así quedaría, pero quiero ver si se puede introducir doble IF en un mismo trigger. Les adjunto la imagen de cómo quedó la sentencia. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Por favor, pon el código como texto, no como imagen. Tú puedes poner los `IF` que quieras en un TRIGGER, pero en este caso, tus comparaciones no son correctas en el planteamiento dices: *pero también si la cantidad que se quiere ordenar es menor o igual a la cantidad existente, deberá actualizar la tabla productos con la nueva existencia.*, tú en el TRIGGER estás evaluando lo contrario: si la cantidad es mayor o igual. Además hablas de *actualizar*, si es así, la consulta debería ser del tipo `UPDATE`, pero en el TRIGGER lo que se ve es un `INSERT`.

Comment: Por favor, coloca el código _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Yo en mi caso si veo las imágenes pero hay otras personas que no tiene tan buena vista como la mía de momento.... , a pesar de estar todo el día delante del ordenador estudiando, por lo que te recomiendo que quites la imagen y ponga eso en tipo texto para una mayor ayuda @Tamara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer es:

## Usar un `TRIGGER` para validar 2 tablas diferentes.

En MySQL no puedes comparar un dato con el de una tabla con un simple `NEW.cantidad > productos.cantidad` , debes ceñirte al SQL y usar un `SELECT`. [Post de referencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/527785/282533)

Si se ejecuta de esa forma desconocerá una tabla y podria salir el error:

```
[42S02][1109] Unknown table 'nombre_tabla' in field list
```

Para poder realizar la comparación que necesitas **debes de trabajar con variables**, existen 3 tipos de variables.

1. Variables definidas por el usuario.
2. Variables locales.
3. Variables del sistema.

La estructura seria la siguiente (utilizando variables locales).

```
DECLARE existencia INT;
 SET existencia= (SELECT cantidad FROM pruebaproducto
            WHERE PruebaProducto.id = NEW.id_producto);
```

También, a la hora de usar tu `DELIMITER $$`, lo estas cerrando con otro delimitador `//`.

Recuerda que el delimitador predeterminado es `;`, es necesario cambiarlo por algo diferente para que MySQL trate las siguientes líneas como un solo comando hasta que alcance su delimitador personalizado. Por ejemplo, el delimitador se cambio a `//` debe cerrarse en `//` y luego puede redefinir el delimitador `;`.

Lo que pide hacer son 2 condiciones.

- Si la cantidad que se quiere ordenar es mayor a la cantidad
  existente, arroja un mensaje usando `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'`.
- Si la cantidad que se quiere ordenar es menor o igual a la cantidad
  existente, deberá actualizar la tabla productos con la nueva
  existencia.

Esto se puede resolver usando un `IF` `ELSE`. Ya que si (`IF`) la cantidad ordenada es mayor a la cantidad existente, por defecto, si no lo es (`ELSE`) , entonces la cantidad será igual o menor.

Aquí es donde **se aplica el uso de variables para hacer la comparativa** en 2 tablas diferentes. Quedando mas o menos así:

```
 IF nueva_compra > existencia
            THEN
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No hay sufucientes productos';

        ELSE
            UPDATE pruebaproducto SET cantidad = nueva_existencia
                WHERE id=new.id_producto;

        END IF;
```

Nota: En el `ELSE` utilice un `UPDATE`, por que se te pide que se actualice la tabla, no un `INSERT INTO` ya que estarías agregando un nuevo registro.

### Comparto la definición completa para que se pueda comparar con tus respectivas tablas.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER TG_existencias BEFORE INSERT
    ON pruebaventa FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE existencia INT;
        DECLARE nueva_compra INT;
        DECLARE nueva_existencia INT;

        SET existencia= (SELECT cantidad FROM pruebaproducto
            WHERE PruebaProducto.id = NEW.id_producto);

        SET nueva_compra=NEW.canitdad_comprada;

        SET nueva_existencia=(existencia-nueva_compra);

        IF nueva_compra > existencia
            THEN
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No hay sufucientes productos';

        ELSE
            UPDATE pruebaproducto SET cantidad = nueva_existencia
                WHERE id=new.id_producto;

        END IF;

    END //
DELIMITER ;

insert into pruebaventa value (0,1,3,31);
insert into pruebaventa value (0,1,3,16);
```

### También aporto las tablas con las que estuve haciendo la prueba.

```
CREATE TABLE PruebaProducto
(   id int auto_increment primary key not null ,
    nombre varchar(50) not null ,
    cantidad int not null
);

CREATE TABLE PruebaCliente
(   id int auto_increment primary key not null ,
    nombre varchar(50) not null ,
);

CREATE TABLE PruebaVenta
(   id_venta int auto_increment primary key not null ,
    id_cliente int,
    id_producto int,
    canitdad_comprada int,

    constraint fkcliente
    foreign key (id_cliente) references PruebaCliente(id),

    constraint fkproducto
    foreign key (id_producto) references PruebaProducto(id)
);

INSERT into PruebaProducto VALUE (0,'MANZANA',10), (0,'PERA',20), (0,'MANGO',30);
INSERT into PruebaCliente value (0,'uno'), (0,'dos'), (0,'tres');
INSERT into pruebaventa value (0,1,1,5), (0,2,2,5),(0,3,3,5);

SELECT * FROM PruebaProducto ;
SELECT * FROM PruebaCliente ;
SELECT * FROM pruebaventa ;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me fue de mucha ayuda entender como funciona el UPDATE junto con el IF ELSE.